# How to display contents in parallel array using Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a program that calculates the average temperature for a month using parallel arrays (it is mandatory to use a parallel array).  I'm new to Java (I'm more familiar with C++) so I get confused with the use of methods.  I know how to compute the averages already, I just need help with setting up the parallel arrays.  This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
      String[] day = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
             "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
      int[] temp = new int [7];
}
   public static int[] getTemp(String[] day, int[] temp)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter temperatures for : " + day[i]);
         for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++)
         {
            temp[i] = scan.nextInt();
         }             
      }
      return temp;
   }
}
```

For now I just want to show the contents in my array before I start computing averages.

Comment: Do you mean a multidimensional array? **What** is a *parallel* array? Did you know you have a semicolon before the opening brace of `getTemp()`? Why?

Comment: I removed the semicolon and changed the position of "return temp;" and now it compiles.  But it still doesn't display the contents of my array.

Comment: A parallel array is one with the same number of elements as another and for which values in corresponding elements are related.

Comment: The above code doesn't call your method... and it doesn't print anything... what is your question again?

Comment: All it does is compile.  It doesn't do anything.  How do I get it to ask for the temperature and display the contents in the array?

Comment: Change `int[] temp = new int [7];` to `int[] temp = getTemp(day, temp)` ,  this method is confusing because it has a nested loop (it will ask the user to enter `day.length * day.length` number of temperatures) and it is both asking and returning an int array. You can create a new array inside the method, there is no need to ask for one as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the parallel array like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] day = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
        int[] temp = initTemp(day);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("temperaure: " + temp[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] initTemp(String[] day) {
        int[] temp = new int[day.length];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter temperatures for " + day[i] + ":");
            temp[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```